# Delphi XE6 - IDE File Open button shuts down the IDE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

Odd behaviour for an IDE, choose File Open from the main file menu or press the file Open button on the toolbar and the IDE shuts down.

Select "Exit" on the File menu to shut down the IDE and it produces the File Open Dialog.

It seems unlikely that this is intentional behaviour or have the programmers gone mad?

Update: It looks like when XE6 is first opened, the buttons behave properly, then reverse when a new vcl application is created.

The machine is Dell latitude Win7 32 bit laptop.

I have installed XE6 on my Win7 64 bit desktop machine and it appears to function correctly.

Comment: Obviously this is either a bug in your installation (more likely) or a bug in the whole software. You should reinstall the IDE first, download it again, or contact Embarcadero for support.

Comment: It's not normal behavior for XE6 - I have it installed on both my work desktop and laptop, and it works perfectly well on both. (Clearly there are others who are using it as well, as this issue  hasn't been reported in QC or any of the forums either, AFAICT.) Seems like you either have a borked installation or a badly buggy third party component; based on your other question about images on the component palette, I'd risk a wager it's the latter (although third-party may mean "your own").

Comment: Since XE6 is brand new, and the first release of each previous Delphi version have had numerous weird bugs as well, it *might* be an IDE bug. Anyway, I would choose to reinstall it again too. If the problem remains, contain Embarcadero/file a bug. Also, make sure to test it before installing any 3rd party components or IDE plug-ins.

Comment: @GolezTrol: Ads XE6 has been out for several weeks now (and went through beta testing before then), it's highly unlikely this is an IDE bug - it would have been reported or mentioned before now. It's highly more likely that the user's component (or some third party component or expert) is causing this issue; remember that design-time component code *actually executes within the IDE*, as do experts and wizards.  The poster's previous question mentions difficulties with installing his own components (being ported from D2007, which also adds Unicode-related issues into the mix).

Comment: @Andy I doubt you have a vanilla XE6. What else did you install?

Comment: @David: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23716367

Comment: @Ken What is your point? I have installed all those components into XE5 with no problem.

Comment: I was experiencing the same issue, and installing Andreas Hausladen‘s IDEFix and Developer extensions packages solved the problem. But I don‘t know the reason.

Answer (score 3):

This can be caused by extra files being added to the IDE's Bin folder. In my case it was the FastMM dlls.

I found the answer on the Embarcardero Forums:
https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=914786#914786

Per Remy's answer

> The IDE's copy protection is being invoked at startup. If unauthorized
>   non-Embarcadero files are placed in the IDE's \bin folder, the
>   actions of the file menu's  Open and Exit items are swapped. You need
>   to find the offending files in the \bin folder and remove them.

The poster there has the issue in XE5, I experienced the issue in Delphi 10.1 Berlin.

Answer (score 1):

With probability close to 1, this is due to one of the design time packages that you have installed in your IDE. Remove these packages one by one until the IDE returns to its normal behaviour. At that point you will have identified the faulty package and can dig deeper to understand why it breaks your IDE.

**Update**

It seems that people other than you are facing the same issue. It is possible that they have installed the same third party components as you that are defective. And of course, it is possible that this is in fact a Delphi IDE defect.

- http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=124919
- https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=104838&tstart=0

Comment: @ david, I have removed all user packages, shut down, rerun XE6, confirmed packages removed. Still does it. I created new vcl forms app, it seemed to be working OK. Closed project, tried to open file and XE6 shut down. At this point, I guess its an XE6 bug. I did actually purchase XE5, but I also purchased the support pack and within 2 days of installing XE5 embarcadero emailed me the upgrade link to XE6, so both are installed.

Comment: Hardly plausible that this could be a delphi bug. Unless it can be reproduced it looks environmental.

Comment: an environmental effect that swaps the actions of the Exit and File Open items?.

Comment: @ David Just done it, vanilla install. Still does it.

Comment: You know what to do next then

Comment: @Andyk: Yes, as in "the environment you've created within the IDE". You need to remember that components, wizards and experts that interact with the IDE at designtime are actually code that is executing in the IDE's environment at designtime. A bug in one of those items can affect the stability and behavior of the IDE itself. As this "bug" has not been reported previously even once AFAICT, chances are extremely high that you've done something to your environment that is causing this issue. Uninstall XE6, delete the related registry keys, and reinstall from scratch.

Comment: @ken except I have them all installed into XE5 and 2007 with no problems.

Comment: @David yes, XE5 was downloaded and installed on March 31st, I had no time to play with it as the email link for the XE6 upgrade came from embarcadero almost immediately. So a virgin XE5 has been on both my machines. I just loaded everything into XE5 and it all works, XE6 does not work properly on either machine.

Comment: You installed extensions into XE6 is my question. Anyway, if you have a vanilla XE6 that behaves this way you need to tell the vendor. Nobody else can fix it.

Comment: @david What do you call extensions?, There are no property editors or other extensions like that, just plain components to go on the palette...Yes I have posted these problems on the Developer network site.

Comment: You need to submit a bug report on QC.

Comment: @Andyk: Do **NOT** install any of your components. Uninstall XE6, delete the HKCU\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\14.0 registry key, delete anything from the Embarcadero folders in the Users\Public\Documents and Users\<yourname>\Documents folders. Then do a new, clean install of XE6, and before installing **a single thing** that didn't come out of the installer see if you can reproduce the issue. (Repeat: Install nothing that wasn't put there by the RAD Studio installer - no third party tools, none of your components, **nothing**.) I have a clean install on Win7 64 with no indication of this problem.

Comment: @Ken I could do that. But then its not a very useful system, it needs to work with my components as 2007 and XE5 does. As it is, its annoying but does not affect the running of the compiler. Its less annoying now I have found a workaround for the palette Icon issues (see my other post). XE6 is definetly buggy, there should be nothing you can do in a standard component with no property editors that can make the Action properties swap over in the IDE file menu.

Comment: @AndyK: You need to do so in order to isolate the problem. If the problem doesn't happen in a clean install, odds are about 99.9% that the problem is in one of your components, and you can start ttrying to determine which one it is and how to fix it. If the problem occurs in the clean install, you'll have the information needed to create a bug report with reproducible steps that can help get it fixed. Ignoring what people are telling you to do to resolve it and just complaining about bugs you can't be sure exist is not leading to a useful system either. If you won't help yourself, how can we?

Comment: As far as "there should be nothing you can do in a standard component", you're 100% wrong. A component that has a representation at design-time **is running code inside the IDE** (the IDE creates an instance of that component and **it's code is executing**. A buggy component can indeed affect the IDE, and it's not a bug in the IDE that causes it - the **code is executing inside the IDE**. If you don't understand that and how it can impact the IDE, you probably shouldn't be writing components yet. Even the order components are loaded can impact things; one order might work, and others fail.

Comment: @ken I am doing the uninstall now. However I continue to use XE5 with no problems. There is no issue with the compiling or the running of the applications at all in XE5 or XE6 its just the IDE in XE6 that has a problem. Its all range checked and overflow checked. However, I can;t vouch for SynEdit or Graphics32 which is also loaded.

Comment: I thought you said earlier that you have reproduced the fault with a vanilla install. If that is not the case then there is no point discussing anything. Reproduce it with a vanilla install and then submit a QC report. But I don't believe that a vanilla install will behave this way. Ask yourself why you alone see this behaviour.

Comment: @David, I uninstalled and reinstalled, but as Ken said, the registry and directories was not cleaned. I'm going to try that next, there's also the possiblity of some interaction between XE5 and XE6.

Comment: This is where a clean VM would come in handy. Ultimately either there's a Delphi bug which only Emba can address, or your installed plugins/extensions are defective. I don't think there's any more that anyone here can say.

Comment: @AndyK: Once again, even the order that components are loaded can affect things. You do not have a bug in XE6 unless a) you can reproduce it with a clean installation of the IDE, or b) show that others have reported the same problem with a clean install of the IDE (reports in QC or the EMBT forums). Until then, you have buggy components or third-party stuff, whether you agree with that or not.

Comment: @ken Do you see any problems on your installation with your own components?  Does your dcr icons load up OK?

Comment: I raised this issue on EDN and I am not the only one with the problem someone else has chirped up...https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=104838&tstart=0.

Comment: @ken Just to confirm, the uninstall, clean and install just finished. First run of vanilla XE6, IDE appears, wait 20 secs, press the File Open button and the IDE shuts down.

Comment: Well, there's a QC report now. But perhaps you need to submit a proper support incident.

Comment: @Andyk: Cannot replicate here. I can run the IDE for 20 seconds, 20 minutes, or 2 hours, and File|Open works correctly both from the menu and toolbar. As you indicate you can replicate this from a clean install, it is an installation issue and you can open a free support case at http://support.embarcadero.com for installation related issues.

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).